# How to style a radio button?

Tags: html, css

I simply don't find any instructions how to style a radio button like the div in my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5SRe/

The div:

```
div { 
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green
}
```

also I would like that when the radio button is selected it has:

```
border: medium solid #000;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radio buttons are part of the [Shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/), which as of yet can't be universally styled across browsers.

The best way currently to get custom radio buttons is to use images or the [checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

Comment: This is not proper solution for the problem. Input, according to W3C is not element with beginning and end tag, so it can not use :after and :before pseudoelement. Better solution is to make label for that input and use pseudoelements there.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) before, it is not cross browser compatible and I would recommend you keep things simpler, but that depends on your personal choice and use case